# How do I search in Discussion Boards from a Form Web Part?

Tags: search

I want to create a "sharepointoverflow.com" solution in a sharepoint, for one of our internal projects.

I have choose a Form Web Part for searching and Discussion Boards for asking questions and replying to them.

How I can create a search algorithm that searches the discussion board?

I type some keywords in the form web part and click Go.

The search algoritm should search for the keyword in the Discussion Board, both in the subject and in the body text.

Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way.

You want to set up a search scope that will only crawl discussion boards.
Create your new scope and for the rules add the property query as 'contentclass' and the equals as 'STS_List_DiscussionBoard'.

Let the scope compile and you now have a search scope that will only return discussion board items which should give you what you need.

Cheers

Comment: I dont have any access to the server side :(
So, are there a solution to my problem that can be solved on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

With Search Server Express I think you can use the Search webparts to target a specific list (or at the very least, a specific site), and set the default search scope to that particular list or site and display this webpart within your Q&A page.

Answer (score 0):

I've configured a scope for the discussions in my SP site.
I'm able to see the discussions in the results, but not the replies and the number of it.
Is there a way to show these information and not only the discussion?

Thanks,
Gg

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.